# Changing the background colour of a React Navigator object

Tags: navigation, react-native

I'm extending a `React.Component` to render a `Navigator`:

```
<Navigator
  renderScene={this.renderScene}
  navigationBar={
    <NavigationBar
      routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
      style={styles.navBar} **// background colour is set here**
  />
/>
```

and passing along the navigator object the scene being rendered:

```
renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
  if(route.maps) {
    return <MapView navigator={navigator} />;
  }
  return <LoginScreen navigator={navigator} />;
}
```

and `MapView` looks something like this:

```
type Props = {
  navigator: Navigator;
}

class BTMapView extends React.Component {
  props: Props;
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    ...
  }
}
```

So now that I can reference the navigator object with `this.props.navigator` how do I use it to override the background colour of its navigation bar with an imperative API call?

SOLUTION:

```
class BTNavigator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      navBarStyle: styles.navBar,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        navigationBar={
          <NavigationBar
            routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
            style={this.state.navBarStyle}
          />
        }
      />
    );
  }

  renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
    ...

    // pass both navigator and a reference to this
    return <LoginScreen navigator={navigator} btNavigator={this} />
  }

  setNavBarStyle(style) {
    this.setState({
      navBarStyle: style,
    });
  }
}
```

Now use `navigator` and `btNavigator`:

```
type Props = {
  navigator: Navigator,
  btNavigator: BTNavigator,
};

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  props: Props;

  foo() {
    this.props.btNavigator.setNavBarStyle({
      backgroundColor: 'black',
    });

    this.props.navigator.push({
      ...
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make `NavigatorWrapper` class that will store `Navigator` and some additional state and method eg.

```
setNavBarRed() {
    this.setState({navBarColor: 'red'});
}
```

In `render()` method render `Navigator` just like you have written above with additional check for `NavigationBar` style. Just set `backgroundColor: this.state.navBarColor` in styles.

And finally, now you can use your prop: `this.props.navigatorWrapper.setNavBarRed()`

Please note that if you are using `connect` from `react-redux` you need to pass `withRef` argument to `connect` call.

Comment: Thanks! Moving the style into `state` and adding a setter function helped me solve the issue.

Comment: Here you are. Please upvote the answer if it was helpful.